# gwt focus on flowpanel or any other panel

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am doing project in gwt. In which i have added multiple flowpanel which contains other things like textboxes, labels and buttons. My question is how to focus on a particular flowpanel. I know which panel to focus, but not found any method to do the focus.

I have also used focuspanel but it just focus on that panel and no scroll event happens if panel is last panel.

Please if anyone knows how to do this, please reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using setFocus on a TextBox that is inside the FlowPanel you wish to focus to.